# DynamicResource doesn't work when combined with AppThemeBinding (Maui)

Tags: maui

I have a ResourceDictionary that contains a Style element.

```
    <Style TargetType="Page" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={DynamicResource Primary}, Dark={DynamicResource Secondary}}" />
    </Style>
```

And I have created two different ResourceDictionies that contain Colors with identical keys.

```
    //Theme 1
    <Color x:Key="Primary">#512BD4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#DFD8F7</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Tertiary">#2B0B98</Color>

    //Theme 2
    <Color x:Key="Primary">#ff0000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#0000ff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Tertiary">#00ff00</Color>
```

The goal is be able to dynamical swap the theme file at runtime. For now, I am just loading a single theme into my App's MergedDictionaries

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Theme1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

However, when I run the app, my page background is White. It's not using any of the colors from my theme.

If I change my Style rule to not using AppThemeBinding, it works as expected. `<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}" />`

If I switch to StaticResources, it also works. `<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Secondary}}" />`

Is it possible to combine AppThemeBinding with DynamicResource?

I've only tested this on Android.

Comment: There is a similar issue on Github [DynamicResource binding not working #5044](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5044).

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked this was an open issue, and I checked again just for this and it seems it's still open.

More information here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13570

For the time being I would recommend having multiple static resources and switching between them on runtime, as long as you don't have a color picker or something, in that case you might have a hard time.

### Update

Well before DynamicResources were a thing that worked in Xamarin Forms (there was a similar issue on XF as well when it first came out), I remember we used to conditionally compile our OnAppearing methods for the view's code-behind with dictionary calls to get the data for eg:

```
var tc1= (Color) Application.Current.Resources["TextColor1"];
var tc2= (Color) Application.Current.Resources["TextColor2"];
```

And now based on my condition I either bind my correct TextColor or just assign it directly to the control.

To avoid doing it over and over again you could just do this once in a base class (can also be done in the base constructor so it's always available).

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information about swapping a static resource at runtime? I was under the impression that Dynamic resources needed to be used in order to do anything at runtime. My goal is dynamically apply a different theme after a user logs in.

Comment: @Dave I have updated my answer have a look

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the OP's original comment, "The goal is be able to dynamical swap the theme file at runtime," to do that, we do something like the following:

```
// RDService should be created as a singleton
public class RDService
{
    private ResourceDictionary ThemeResource { get; set; } = new();

    public void UpdateResources(IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> rds)
    {
        var root = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        // In an early implementation, the root remove/add steps were not done.
        // Instead, the ThemeResource was cleared and updated in place. That turned
        // out badly because the app went into an infinite loop when setting the
        // ContentPage style.
        root.Remove(ThemeResource);

        var rscList = ThemeResource.MergedDictionaries;
        rscList.Clear();

        // Resources added last have precedence if keys are duplicated in different
        // resources.
        foreach (var rd in rds)
        {
            rscList.Add(rd);
        }

        root.Add(ThemeResource);
    }
}
```

*(Our actual implementation is a bit more complex than this because we provide functions to sort, add, and remove resources, but hopefully this sample captures the gist of it.)*

So, assuming rdService is a singleton, for the OP the initial theme could be set like this:

```
rdService.UpdateResources([Theme1]);
```

and then later dynamically changed by doing this:

```
rdService.UpdateResources([Theme2]);
```

Resources updated in this way can be accessed using `DynamicResource` bindings in the .xaml, but only for page instances created *after* the resources have been updated using RDService. For this reason, `DynamicResource` bindings in the App.xaml file will not recognize changes made using RDService.

This can also be a problem on your MainPage, since usually it is only created once and thus dynamic changes using RDService will be ignored. One work-around is to insert a dummy empty MainPage whose OnAppearing function automatically routes the app to the real main page. Then, if RDService is used to dynamically update the resources, you can go back to the dummy main page, which will then re-launch the real main page so it gets the resource updates.

Another work-around would be to set the MainPage's visual element properties explicitly in the code behind using `Application.Current.Resources[]` if the resources are updated.

The RDService approach has worked for us both in Xamarin and in MAUI.